# SQL REPLACE not working

Tags: php, sql, mysql

There are only two columns and I want to UPDATE only if `menu_id` exists.  Otherwise I want to insert a new row.  Here's my query:

```
REPLACE `dol_subs_menu_access` 
SET `menu_id` = '{$aVars['menu_item']}',
`mlevels` = '{$sMemLevels}'
```

This creates a new row everytime. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `REPLACE` in sql does a string replace for a substring in a longer string.  Sounds like you want to `UPDATE` the actual contents of the field to something else, is that correct?  Also what DB are you using?

Comment: @JNK: See [MySQL's REPLACE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html).

Comment: MySQL Sorry, yeah I guess update is what I'm looking for. But if the record isn't in there how do I insert a new one?  I wanted to keep it to a single query

Comment: Then `REPLACE` would be the command to use, wouldn't it?

Comment: @OMG - Thanks for correcting me!  I had no idea MySQL had that syntax.

Comment: Can you use a stored procedure and call that?  Then in the stored procedure call the update and if the rowcount is 0 then you know it doesn't exist and you can then do an insert?

Comment: @Ponies Good thinking, both columns were primary. I made just menu_id primary and it works now.

Comment: @whatshakin: Interesting that the REPLACE didn't like a composite primary key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are either of the columns in your statement the primary key? My guess is they aren't, which is what the [REPLACE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) (not to be confused with the string replacement function) needs to determine if it is replacing vs inserting...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [mySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  This will allow you to insert a record or update a record if it already exists.  You will need to include the primary key in your query though.

here is an example query from their documentation page:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

I think it would look something like this for your query (test it first though)

```
INSERT INTO `dol_subs_menu_access` (menu_id,mlevels) 
       VALUES ('{$aVars['menu_item']}','{$sMemLevels}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mlevelsMemLevels='{$sMemLevels}';
```

Comment: or `mlevelsMemLevels = VALUES(mlevelsMemLevels)`, no need to put the string in twice.